# error: the method [] was called on null. tried calling ()[merchantId]

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the list of products by shop from the firestore. However, getting the following error:

```
I/flutter ( 7294): NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 7294): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 7294): Tried calling: []("merchantId")
```

I am using FutureBuilder to get shop data and StreamBuilderWrapper to get the products:

```
class Shop extends StatelessWidget {

Widget getProductsAndImages(BuildContext context, String outletID) {
return StreamBuilderWrapper(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    stream: productsRef.doc(outletID).collection('products')
        .orderBy('dateTime', descending: true).snapshots(),
    itemBuilder: (_, DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
      ProductModel posts = ProductModel.fromJson(snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
      return posts.productId != null
          ? Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12.0),
        child:
        ProductItem(productName: posts.proName!, productPrice: posts.price!,
            count: posts.count!, images: posts.images!,
          category: posts.category!, productDescription: posts.productDescription!,
            productId: posts.productId!),
      )
          : Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text('No products'),
        ),
      );
    });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final outletData = Provider.of<OutletData>(context);
final outletId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
print('outlet id--->>> $outletId');

return Scaffold(
    appBar: appHeader(context),
    backgroundColor: color2,
    extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
    body:  Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
    Container(
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage("assets/images/background.jpg"),
  fit: BoxFit.cover,),
),
),
FutureBuilder(
      future: outletData.getOutletById(outletId),
      builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting ||
            snapshot.data == null) {
          return
            Center(
              child: Text("Юм олдсонгүй"),
            );
        }
        return snapshot.data.length == 0
            ? Center(
          child: Text("Бүтээгдэхүүн байхгүй"),
        )
            : SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ShopHeader(
                outletName: snapshot.data()[outletName],
                outletImage: snapshot.data()[outletImg],
                location: snapshot.data()[outletLocation],
                description: snapshot.data()[outletIntro],
                phoneNum: snapshot.data()[outletPhone],
                merchantId: snapshot.data()[merchantId],
                outletId: outletId,
                outletRating: snapshot.data()['outletRating'],
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: Text(
                  "Recommended products:",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 17,
                    color: Colors.black54,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ListView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                  return
                    getProductsAndImages(context, outletId);
              
                },
                
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    )
]));
}
}
```

my getOutletById method is in the provider class:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getOutletById(String outId) async {
var outletsById;
final Map<String, dynamic> idOutlet = {};
_outletMerchant.clear();
try {
  outletsById =
  await firestore.collection(outletsCollection).doc(outId).get();
  var outletResponse = outletsById.data();

  var outletMerchantData = await firestore
      .collection(allUserCollection)
      .doc(outletResponse[merchantId])
      .get();

  var merchantResponse = outletMerchantData.data();

  _outletMerchant.addAll(merchantResponse!);
  print(_outletMerchant);

  idOutlet.addAll(outletResponse);

  print(merchantResponse[merchantId]);
} catch (err) {
  print(err);
}
return idOutlet;
}
```

print() method prints nothing here my firestore database is as follows:
[image]
[image]

You can see that there is the merchantId for the outlets collection. where is the error here?

Comment: I think the issue occurs because you don't decode data from Json.